# How to communicate Node JS and Kinect?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openni, openkinect

I want to do some stuff using kinect and my research took me to two libs, libfreenect and OpenNi, the first one apparently just extract video data, am I right? The second one was acquired by Apple and dissolved, however some of the binary data and documentation was recovered by structure.io and this library does give the complete Kinect data. My idea is to use a socket.io server to process the Kinect input data and send it to the browser, then use JavaScript to process it on the client. My question is, does anyone here has achieved such thing? And if so, could you give me some guidance on how to achieve this or where to start please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. in order to get answers to questions you need to provide a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically this site works best with some code in the question, and asking for library suggestions is typically [Off Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

For Kinect for Windows V2 =>

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/kinect2 [I've used it]

For kinect v1 =>

1. https://github.com/nguyer/node-kinect
2. http://metaduck.com/09-kinect-browser-node.html
3. http://blog.whichlight.com/post/53241512333/streaming-kinect-data-into-the-browser-with-nodejs
4. http://depthjs.media.mit.edu/

Answer (score 0):

This library achieves something similar to what you were looking to do. It uses Kinect2 (mentioned in another response) to get the Kinect data, but also lets you stream it to another browser.

https://github.com/kinectron/kinectron